# Is this bathroom plumbing code compliant?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, renovation

We're having some contractors redo our master bathroom. We wanted to relocate the toilet and shower but the plumbing they've laid does not look okay to me. I've labeled the image below with the new locations of everything.

For context, the toilet is going where the shower used to be. The shower is replacing the old tub. And a new double vanity is taking place of the old vanity and toilet.

I have a few concerns with their plumbing:

1. Is it okay to have the run of the shower drain and vanity plumbing go up and over the toilet drain like that?
2. Is the 135 degree bend in the toilet line okay or will that cause problems down the line

Thank you all for your time

[image]

Comment: Compliant to code in what jurisdiction?  Regardless of code, that looks problematic.

Answer (score 2):

No, no plumbing code I'm aware of would permit that weirdness. The tee fitting shown does not even appear to be a drainage pipe fitting, so would be totally impermissible. 135 degrees is the maximum change of direction in a drain line allowed before a cleanout is required. You can see that toilet drain is headed right towards a further bend, meaning a cleanout is required right there, but that requirement seems to have been ignored. You are right to be concerned.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is that 135° change of direction horizontal only or does it include vertical changes? I could see where a vertical change might be less susceptible to clogging, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I assume they intend to connect the side outlet of the tee to the existing pipe next to the 3" line. This arrangement would not pass any plumbing code. Here is how I would pipe this (they would need to chip up a bit more of the floor to make room):

[image]

Caveats of this layout are:

- Local code allows wet venting
- The length of the 3" pipe run to the toilet is under 12 feet long
- The pipe to the shower is 2" and the run is under 8 feet long
- The pipe to the double basins is either 2" or 3" depending on local code sizing of wet vents requierments